# Float with %-width inside an absolute positioned div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've done this before but not with bootstrap and I can't remember the solution last time either..

**What I want**: a responsive design using bootstrap where each column is given a width using percentage.

**What the customer wants**: nice transitions between pages where the old one slides out and the new slides in.

**The solution**: `$(".page").css("left", something)` and put on some transition properties using CSS3.

**What is required for such a solution**: only elements with absolute position can use top and left property.

**The problem:** The columns are no longer responsive now that they are hosted inside an absolute positioned div! :(

```
<div id="pagewrapper">
    <div class="container page">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <p>Bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <p>Bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
#pagewrapper {
    /* 
    margin and padding because I have a fixed header and footer 
    */
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 60px 25px;
    position: relative;
}

.page {
    position: absolute;
    /* mixins for LESS I dont have here now
    .transition-duration(2s);
    .transition-property(left);
    */
}
</style>
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/979/). The `position: absolute` is commented out for now, ucomment it and you see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

top and left property can also be used by relative positioned elements.

```
.page{position: relative; left: 100%;}
```

position relative shouldn't alter your responsive layout and will allow you to use your css animations.

Comment: I don't alway RTFM, but when I do, someone already posted an answer. Thanks mate!

Comment: Also I'd like to blame the MDN documentation for stating that only fixed and absolute positioned elements can use left, but then I read w3school and for the first time in my life w3school actually had some useful information!